# What is the shape of 3D tensor by 3D tensor multiplication in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

So I have a code from github on NLP task that multiples 3D tensor by another 3D tensor, both of which have the same shape so the multiplication looks like (batch,bucket,bucket)*(batch,bucket,bucket). 
Exact code with some modification, though of not so big importance is as follows:

`bilin = tf.batch_matmul(lin,inputs2, adj_y=True)`

where lin and inputs2 is of the above shape. So what would be the resulting shape?

PS. I know this is very old version of tensorflow, but this is not so important I guess.

Comment: I couldn't find the function tf.batch_matmul() in the documentation. Which version are you using ?

Comment: I am using version 0.8, and here is the link for the tf code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py